# Pulling Freebase data in Google Refine

Tags: semantics, freebase, google-refine

I'm fairly new to Google Refine and Frebase.
I want to use use the internet/websites list, but the dump doesn't contain the website URL, it's however accessible in related "official website" object.

In Refine, how is it possible to fetch this data based on a website ID (/m/02nqp6l)?

## Dataset (internet/websites)

http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/latest/browse/internet/website.tsv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic that you cite doesn't actually have a link for the official web site.   You might be better off looking at a topic which does like http://www.freebase.com/inspect/en/hubpages_inc for the same company and look at how the web site URL is connected (via the /common/topic/webpage property to http://www.freebase.com/inspect/m/03gnm5n)